# Evaluate the performance of my ASP.NET app?

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I'm nearly done building a small web app and since deploying it the performance has been fairly awful. It doesn't have anything in terms of graphics, primarily a bunch of datagrids, which are databound through a number of LINQ queries. But it's painfully slow... I'm inclined to point a finger at the host (ahem... GD) but where should I be looking to be sure it isn't my code?

Comment: Take a look at the size of the page being downloaded.  Fiddler or any of the browser debug tools will show this.  There's a good chance you are downloading much more data than you realized and the slowness is caused by the bandwidth.

Comment: Can you run it locally? Do you get better speed?

Comment: @logixologist Yes, much better which is why I'm tempted to assume it's the host but I want to make sure before I point fingers.

Comment: There have literally been [books written on this subject](https://www.amazon.com/ASP-NET-Site-Performance-Secrets-Perdeck/dp/1849690685). The answer textbox only allows 30000 characters. You might want to read the books.

Comment: There are lots of performance analysing tools such as dot.trace that come with free trials

Comment: Voting to close this answer as too broad, for reasons MIke mentioned above. If you want to find out why your app is running slow, you need to figure out how to time it so you can see what specifically is taking so long. Listing out all the possible reasons does not make for a good answer, and thus this question is not suitable for this site.

Comment: @mason I think that people, such as myself, that are relative beginners would find this an interesting question and the fact that it garnered as many helpful responses as it did in a short time is an indication that it's a subject of broad interest.  A number of people made very helpful, succinct responses and in fact pointed me towards solving my problem.  Essentially you're saying "solve your problem and then ask".  If I knew how to analyze the problem adequately, I wouldn't have needed to ask.

And to everyone that took time out to provide suggestions... thank you!

Comment: Just because something is helpful does not mean it is appropriate content for this site. And yes, you are expected to do basic research on your application to figure out why it's slow. Could be any of hundreds of reasons, and rather than having suggestions thrown out by people who know nothing about your app, you should take the time to do basic research to see what areas of the app are slow.

Answer (score 2):

Slowness can be due to numerous reasons, below is a small todo list:-

1) Check size of the page using developer tool.

2) Use .Net profiler tool to see if particular area is causing the slownees of the application.

3)Check the sql query generated by linq to sql, optimize if needed.

4)If you are frequently visiting database for master data or the one that doesn't change frequently. You can use caching here.

Once you have identified pain area you can figure out enough resources on internet, but without knowing cause you cannot look for remedy.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WebForms, turn viewstate off for your grid controls if you are using them for display only.  Keeping state in grid controls kills performance.

Comment: thanks I wasn't aware of that... I'll try it. Can you clarify what you mean by display only?  Vs...? These grids are used for editing as well.

Comment: Thanks everyone!!! Those are awesome suggestions and comments!  I will use them to do some homework and report back!

Comment: I meant for when you are not editing.  In that case, you may need to find other performance improvements.  Vinay had some very good advice.  Reducing the size of the data in the grid where you can would be helpful too. So if you can add filtering to the query that returns the dataset for the grid before you display it, that will help.

Comment: Thank you.  I thought that's what you meant but didn't want to assume I understood correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not really an answer, but when it comes to performance issues without known source, one should look for a profiler.

There are lots of performance testing options for a search query `ASP.NET profiler`. The first link from Google suggests [this "how to"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s0xxa1d.aspx) from MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the amount of data and especially if you are querying across entities requiring JOINs, LINQ might not create the most performant code.  I would recommend using a LINQ profiler like EF-Profiler to see what is running.  You might have an N+1 query situation where there are hundreds of queries running per page load.

http://hibernatingrhinos.com/products/EFProf

Also if your data grids are loading the entire dataset into memory/the page and doing the filtering client side, that can result in poor performance.  How many rows get returned at a time and how many appear on the page?

Comment: there are multiple joins and I am loading the entire dataset, but at this point that's not much.  Maybe a hundred rows total, with 6 or seven columns per

Comment: Are the JOINs something that you are coding or relying on LINQ/EF to create?  Are you using the Include() functionality of EF?

Comment: A bit of both Michael, but not using "Include()" anywhere that I recall

Comment: I'm willing to bet you have an N+1 query somewhere (or in multiple places).  Those are probably one of the most common performance killers in any web application.